# Nativescript Angular 2 two way binding performance issue

Tags: javascript, angular, nativescript

*My question is actually about observables and angular. I am using them within Nativescript.*

I am developing a Nativescript application which has lots of components on same view. And I have a service that I called GameBridge and this service is being injected to all components. I am experiencing performance issues because of the two binding at the moment. Let me draw my current structure.

**GameBridgeService**

```
...
GameEngine -> GameInstance -> Somethingelse -> Player
GameEngine -> Somethingelse -> Translator
GameEngine -> ModuleManager -> ModuleX
(And many more deep relations)
...
```

**Component Structure**

```
...
GameSceneComponent - > Status
                       Logs
                       Items
                       Skills
                       Jobs
                       Locales
                       Market
                       (Some more things)
...
```

When Status component is visible, Logs is not visible but it still renders. I can't use ngIf because navigation gets slower on component changes.

At the moment I am injecting GameBridge to all components using

```
constructor(public gameBridge: GameBridgeService)
```

And accessing the things I need with

```
[ngClass]="{success: gameBridge.gameEngine.activeGame.player.getPlayerStat(req.requirement).value >= req.value}"
```

I am wondering if passing data to component with attributes will improve performance? I will only inject **GameBridgeService** into **GameSceneComponent** and pass data to child components with `@Input`

```
<character-status [pageChangeCallback]="thePageCallback"
   [name]="gameBridge.gameEngine.activeGame.player.name"
   avatar="res://f1"
   [health]="gameBridge.gameEngine.activeGame.player.health"
   [morale]="gameBridge.gameEngine.activeGame.player.morale"
   [energy]="gameBridge.gameEngine.activeGame.player.energy"
   [money]="gameBridge.gameEngine.activeGame.player.money"
   [job]="gameBridge.gameEngine.activeGame.player.playerJob"></character-status>
```

If it won't fix my problem, how can I create better structure?